# Is there a way to avoid the recursion limit in my Turtle-program?

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle


WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 1000

#Screen setup
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.title(" " *150  + "Test_GIU")
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(1000, 1000)

#Pen
pen = Turtle("circle")
pen.pensize = 5
pen.color("green")
pen.speed(-1)


def dragging(x, y):  # These parameters will be the mouse position
    pen.ondrag(None)
    pen.setheading(pen.towards(x, y))
    pen.goto(x, y)
    pen.ondrag(dragging)

def click_on_c():
    screen.reset()
    pen = Turtle("circle")
    pen.pensize = 5
    pen.color("green")
    pen.speed(-1)
    pen.ondrag(dragging)


def main():  # This will run the program
    turtle.listen()    
    
    pen.ondrag(dragging)  # When we drag the turtle object call dragging
    turtle.onkeypress(click_on_c, "c")
    screen.mainloop()  # This will continue running main()    

main()
```

This is my code, im pretty new to it, so its not very good, but its my first real project. I´ve already tried to increase the recursin limit, but it crashes even if I set it to 10000. I also tried to catch the error with an try and exept block, but it also doesnt work.

Comment: You probably only need to call `ondrag` once per pen...

Comment: ^^ remove all `ondrag` calls, except the one you have in `main`. NB: the comment on `mainloop()` is not correct (it doesn't execute `main` repeatedly -- it deals with monitoring the event queue)

Comment: @trincot , I tried removing it, but without those ondrag calls, i actually cant move it at all, after i reset the turtle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a simpler design where instead of calling `screen.reset()` and recreating the turtle, we instead call `pen.reset()` to clear the drawing:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 1000

def dragging(x, y):  # Parameters are the mouse position
    pen.ondrag(None)
    pen.setheading(pen.towards(x, y))
    pen.goto(x, y)
    pen.ondrag(dragging)

def click_on_c():
    pen.reset()
    pen.pensize = 5
    pen.color("green")
    pen.speed('fastest')

# Screen setup
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.title("Test_GUI")
screen.bgcolor("black")

# Pen
pen = Turtle("circle")
pen.pensize = 5
pen.color("green")
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.ondrag(dragging)

screen.onkeypress(click_on_c, "c")
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

We have to reset some aspects of the pen after calling `reset()` as that call clears the settings back to the defaults.